# How can I set the owner attribute (not managed by) from an AD group by Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm looking for some help on how to get and set the owner attribute (not managed by) on an AD group by Powershell.

After seeing a lot of documentation on Google and other websites, I only find some solutions for the Managed By property...

Do you have some information to help me on my path to the solution?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Set-ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adgroup) cmdlet doesn't have an Owner parameter, so it's a little more tricky. But as is the case with all the AD cmdlets, you can use the `-Clear` and `-Replace` parameters to work with any attributes that aren't exposed as parameters, and `-Add` and `-Remove` for multi-value attributes.

The [`owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-owner) attribute must be set to the distinguished name of the owner account. So you can use [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser) to find the user and use the [`DistinguishedName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adobject.distinguishedname) property from it.

For example, setting `MyUser` as the owner of `MyGroup` would look like this:

```
Set-ADGroup MyGroup -Replace @{owner = (Get-ADUser MyUser).DistinguishedName}
```